# Ghostscript 9.1.4 not printing when published on IIS with website built in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ghostscript

I am using GhostScript's print functionality in my web application. It works well if I use GhostScript in web app and publish on IIS.

When I consume the GhostScript in MVC 4 application and print locally, it works fine. But when I publish the MVC 4 web app on IIS, it does not print any.

I have checked all my settings related with account and printer. All are fine.

Comment: It would be good if you could show the code how you are calling the Ghostscript and which parameters do you use.

Comment: This is mostly gibberish as far as Ghostscript developers are concerned. Is there a translation of this to something that is relevant to Ghostscript ?

Comment: BTW, there is no Ghostscript 9.1.4 -- I presume you mean 9.14 release